# Is there any way to check status of Server socket in C#?

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm beginner C# developer with Socket programming.

What I want to Is that I want to check on the status of server socket.

Sometimes, My Server Socket Which is created by this options

```
new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream,
                ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

just closed by some reasons (I don't know why .. T_T)

So, I want to re-open if my server socket is down so that my client can connect.

Is there any way to re-open?

Comment: I am trying to think to make one thread which is for checking status of server socket. If server is down, thread will re-open automatically, but I'm not sure this method is right. At first, want to check that is there better way to check it

Comment: Why would you do this? Shouldn't you devote your efforts into *discovering why the socket closes in the first place* rather than trying to paper over the cracks? This is like asking for help with strategies for mopping the floor rather than spending time to *fix the leak*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than periodically looking to see if your socket is still open, you should attach an event handler to the event that fires when your socket is closed, and use that moment to do something with the socket such as reopen it. In terms of why it closes though (because they shouldn't), be sure that your connection processing logic is well thought out and properly multi threaded (or use the async methods, which will establish threaded workers for you under the hood). You might have a situation where your socket is "closing" because you're not correctly returning to a listening state ready for the next connection in good time.

The general pattern should be to accept a connection and return to listening as soon as possible, handing connection processing off to another thread or worker. If you don't do this, and instead try to deal with the client entirely in the same threaded context as you accepted the connection, if the client stops talking or goes away unexpectedly, it kills your socket

We really need to see more of your connection handling logic to know if things are well in this regard; posting a snippet of how the socket is created isn't really enough